# How do I specify build arguments when starting a TFS build from the command line with tfsbuild.exe?

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

For my Team Build process, I have created Work Flow activities that control deployment. I want to choose at runtime whether to deploy the build.

So, I need to send `Deploy=true` or `false` as an input to the work flow runtime initiation.

I can do this by defining a Work Flow custom metadata value with an internal argument.  I can then set the `Deploy` value at runtime via the **Queue Build** dialog under the **Parameters** tabs.

My question is: How do I specify my custom variable when starting a TFS build from the command line with `tfsbuild.exe start`?

Comment: Curt, have you ever find a solution for that? I found the question you asked on VS Team Foundation forum but it also is unanswered. Were you able to find out how to pass a parameter from the command line into the build workflow?

Answer (score 4):

The command line parameter is called `/msBuildArguments`

```
TfsBuild start teamProjectCollectionUrl teamProject definitionName
               [/dropLocation:dropLocation] [/getOption:getOption]
               [/priority:priority] [/customGetVersion:versionSpec]
               [/requestedFor:userName] [/msBuildArguments:args] [/queue]
               [/shelveset:name [/checkin]] [/silent]
```

You can use: `tfsbuild start http://yourserver:8080/tfs/ YourProject YourBuild Definition /msBuildArguments:"Deploy=true"`

Comment: As a side note, if using TFS with Git, and you want to specify the commit ID(hash), syntax is as follows: TFSBuild start teamProjectCollectionUrl teamProject definitionName /queue /getOption:Custom /customGetVersion:LG:ref:<hash>